# How can I add the last paragraph with the basic code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying of making the lyrics of 99 Bottles of Beer

This is what I've got on the last line:

> 1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.
> Take one down and pass it around,
> no more bottle of beer on the wall.

How can I put another line said(With the N capital letter)

> No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.
> Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.

```js
var beer = 99;
while (beer >= 0) {
  var words = "bottles";
  if (beer === 1) {
    words = "bottle";
  }
  console.log(beer + " " + words + " of beer on the wall, " + beer + " " + words + " of beer.Take one down and pass it around, ");
  beer--;
  if (beer === 1) {
    words = "bottle";
  }
  if (beer === 0) {
    beer = "no more";
  }
  console.log(beer + " " + words + " of beer on the wall.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the console.log under the if loop

```js
var beer = 99;
while (beer >= 0) {
  var words = beer === 1 ? "bottle" : "bottles";
  console.log(beer + " " + words + " of beer on the wall, " + beer + " " + words + " of beer. Take one down and pass it around, ");

  beer--;

  words = beer === 1 ? "bottle" : "bottles";

  if (beer === 0) {
    beer = "no more";
    console.log(beer + " " + words + " of beer on the wall.");
    console.log("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.");
  } else {
    console.log(beer + " " + words + " of beer on the wall.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the other answers for extensions of your existing code

Here is a rewrite as DRY as I can get it.

```js
const plur = (word,count) => count === 0 ? `no more ${word}s` : `${count} ${word}${count === 1 ? "" :  "s"}`;
const capitalize = str => `${str.slice(0,1).toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1)}`;
const onTheWall = 'of beer on the wall';
for (var beer = 99; beer >= 0; beer--) {
    let beerText = plur("bottle",beer);
    let nextBeerText = plur("bottle",beer-1);
    const lines = [
    `${beerText} ${onTheWall}, ${beerText} of beer.`,
     beer > 0 ? `Take one down and pass it around,` : `Go to the store and buy some more,`,
     `${beer > 0 ? nextBeerText : plur("bottle", 99)} ${onTheWall}.`
    ];
    if(beer === 0) lines[0] =  capitalize(lines[0]); // capitalise the "N" on 0 beers
    console.log(lines.join("\n"));
}
```

Here is another for fun and education

```js
const maxBeers = 99;
const plur = (word, count) => count === 0 ? `no more ${word}s` : `${count} ${word}${count === 1 ? "" : "s"}`;
const capitalize = str => `${str.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1)}`;
const onTheWall = 'of beer on the wall';

const song = Array.from({ length: maxBeers + 1 }, (_, beer) => {
    beer = maxBeers - beer; // Reverse the count
    let beerText = plur("bottle", beer);
    let nextBeerText = plur("bottle", beer - 1);
    
    let lines = [
        `${beerText} ${onTheWall}, ${beerText} of beer.`,
        beer > 0 ? `Take one down and pass it around,` : `Go to the store and buy some more,`,
        `${beer > 0 ? nextBeerText : plur("bottle", maxBeers)} ${onTheWall}.`
    ];

    if (beer === 0) lines[0] = capitalize(lines[0]); // Capitalize the "N" on 0 beers
    return lines.join("\n");
});

console.log(song.join("\n---\n"));
```